# Tool to create a call diagram for KornShell?

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

Is there a tool available to create call diagrams or create other documentation from a KornShell (ksh) script?

Comment: Call diagrams of what? Shell scripts?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190427/shell-documentation-bash-ksh

Comment: @Neil, Yes shell scripts in general, Korn specifically.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) or [umlgraph](http://www.umlgraph.org/). Search google for more

Comment: I want a tool to automatically create the graphs, not make me do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Do your own parsing (simple string matching might be sufficient) of the script and use [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to generate a graph?

Comment: It's what I'm working on, but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel if I don't have to.